# Error:(56, 0) Cause: org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test_Decorated cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

Tags: java, groovy, intellij-idea, build, gradle

I have this `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
//
//    configurations.all*.exclude(group: 'com.sun.jersey', module: 'jersey-bundle')
//    configurations.all*.exclude(group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module:'jackson-databind')


    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'

    compile 'com.google.inject:guice:4.0-beta5'
    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.18.3'
    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.18.3'

    //testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}


sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main']
        }
    }

    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main']
        }
    }
}


test {
    testLogging {
// Show that tests are run in the command-line output
        events 'started', 'passed'
    }
}


task testBaseLineGenerator(type: test) {
    systemProperties['test.single'] = 'BaseLineGenerator'
}

task testTotalLatency(type: test) {
    systemProperties['test.single'] = 'TotalLatencyTest'
}
```

I get an Intellij error, once I have added:

```
task testBaseLineGenerator(type: test) {
    systemProperties['test.single'] = 'BaseLineGenerator'
}

task testTotalLatency(type: test) {
    systemProperties['test.single'] = 'TotalLatencyTest'
}
```

and I get this error:

```
Error:(56, 0) Cause: org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test_Decorated cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

tried the two options it suggests, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to solve my problem:

I changed to `task testBaseLineGenerator(type: Test) {`

`Test` instead of `test`

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: but there is no more information. what do you think I should add? It solved my problem

Comment: then you should edit this to mention that making this change solved your problem and marked it as accepted

Comment: I had a similar problem with a custom jar task and the problem was that type should have been "Jar" rather than "jar".